# When using "dumpsys meminfo" on Android, what does "PAGECACHE_OVERFLOW" mean?

Tags: android

I am exploring a problem where my App becomes unable to store data in its sqlite db.
When I looked at the 'dumpsys meminfo' results for my app, I discovered the following:

```
SQL

heap: 265

MEMORY_USED: 265

PAGECACHE_OVERFLOW: 177

MALLOC_SIZE: 50
```

What does `PAGECACHE_OVERFLOW` mean ? If it's bad, are there any suggestions to avoiding it ?

Comment: Looks like you are using too much memory - maybe you are statically allocating a lot of objects? If you dynamically allocate them then they may get garbage collected when the system needs more memory.